# Pausing timer when on_pause is called doesnt seem to work (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

On Android, i' m trying to pause my update_time method when on_pause is called, and resume it when
on_resume is called.
In other words i' m trying to pause the timer when the app is minimized and resume it when the app
is resumed.
I understand that the Clock keeps running on background, but i cant figure out
why the code doesnt work. It looks like the check "if self.sw_started==True" is ignored or "self.sw_started" never becomes False.
ex: I open the app, it starts counting.Then i minimise it and wait for a few seconds.
When i resume it, it is not continuing from where it was, which is the behavior i'm looking for.

Thank you very very much for your time, and sorry for my bad english!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sw_started = False
        self.sw_seconds = 0
        #self.tmp_sw_seconds = 0 #this way doesnt work either
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 1)

        self.lbl=Label(text="0")
        return self.lbl

    def on_start(self):
        self.start_timer()

    def update_time(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started==True:
            self.sw_seconds += nap
            print(round(self.sw_seconds))
            self.lbl.text=str(round(self.sw_seconds))

    def reset_timer(self):
        self.sw_started = False
        self.sw_seconds = 0

    def start_timer(self):
        self.sw_started = True

    def stop_timer(self):
        self.sw_started=False

    def on_pause(self):
        self.stop_timer()
        # self.tmp_sw_seconds = self.sw_seconds #this way doesnt work either
        print("timer paused")
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        # self.sw_seconds = self.tmp_sw_seconds #this way doesnt work either
        self.start_timer()
        print("timer resumed")

        pass
MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `sw_started` to `sw_started = BooleanProperty(False)`. This will enable you to observe its current-state whenever its value (here, `bool`) changes.

Next, to make it happen you can bind that to any desired callback method or just use `on_`prop method.

Thus your updated code should now look like,

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty


class MainApp(App):
    sw_started = BooleanProperty(False)
    
    def on_sw_started(self, *args):
        # This will call meth. update_time whenever attr. sw_started changes.
        self.update_time(args)
    
    def build(self):
        self.frequency = 1.0
#        self.bind(sw_started = self.update_time)
        self.sw_seconds = 0
        #self.tmp_sw_seconds = 0 #this way doesnt work either
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, self.frequency)

        self.lbl=Label(text="0")
        return self.lbl

    def on_start(self):
        self.sw_started = True
#        self.start_timer()

    def update_time(self, *args):
        if self.sw_started:
#        if self.sw_started==True:
            self.sw_seconds += self.frequency
            print(int(self.sw_seconds))
            self.lbl.text=str(int(self.sw_seconds))

    def reset_timer(self):
        self.sw_started = False
        self.sw_seconds = 0

#    def start_timer(self):
#        self.sw_started = True

#    def stop_timer(self):
#        self.sw_started=False

    def on_pause(self):
        self.sw_started = False
#        self.stop_timer()
        # self.tmp_sw_seconds = self.sw_seconds #this way doesnt work either
        print("timer paused")
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        # self.sw_seconds = self.tmp_sw_seconds #this way doesnt work either
#        self.start_timer()
        print("timer resumed")
        self.sw_started = True

#        pass
MainApp().run()
```